# Do flags in Golang absolutely need values?

Tags: go, flags

With the flag package in golang, can I have flags that I only need to know the presence of them? Like rails -s, the flag "s" does not have any value, but program can know the presence of the flag s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in the [flag package documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/flag/), it says that one of the possible command line flag syntaxes is `-flag`.  You should try making a boolean flag with the `Bool` or `BoolVar` functions and see if it works the expected way.